# Finding the surface of the intersection between a rectangle and a triangle?

Tags: computational-geometry

Is there a generic way to quickly find the area of an intersection between a rectangle and a triangle ?

I've been thinking about Montecarlo-based ways, but it seems a little bit too heavy for what I'm trying to do... By the way, I don't mind if it's an approximation, but I need to do it quickly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could clip the triangle with the rectangle and add the areas of the subsequent triangles.

http://www.authenticsociety.com/about/PolygonRectangleClipping

Comment: The link seems to have been hacked.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Sutherland-Hodgman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman_algorithm) clipping algorithm, then the [polygon area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Simple_polygons) formula.